What are the current fees?
What are the current fees for transactions on Ethereum network?
I have NodeJS script which asks me for:

tx={..., value: ethers.parseEther("0.3") ... }
gasLimit: 21000
maxFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits("100", "gwei")
maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits("2", "gwei")
.transfer(... , ethers.parseUnits("1400", 6))

What are reasonable values for these parameters today?
And what these parameters mean?

You can get the current fees on https://etherscan.io/gastracker.
tx={..., value: ethers.parseEther("0.3") ... } This is the amount of Ether that is sent in the transaction. ethers.parseEther("0.3") converts 0.3 Ether to Wei.
gasLimit: 21000 This is the maximum amount of gas you're willing to pay for the transaction. 21000 gas is the amount of gas that is used for sending Ether on the Ethereum network.
maxFeePerGas This is the maximum fee per gas that you're willing to pay for the transaction. Given the current network conditions, you can set it to 7 Gwei.
maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits("2", "gwei") The max priority fee per gas (also known as the tip) is the amount paid to miners to incentivize them to prioritize this transaction. ethers.parseUnits("2", "gwei") converts 2 Gwei to Wei. Given the current network conditions, you can set it to 3 Gwei.
.transfer(... , ethers.parseUnits("1400", 6)) I'm not sure what this is. Could be a transfer of an ERC20 token?

transfer(... , ethers.parseUnits("1400", 6)) - yes, this USDT token, need to transfer 1400 USDT. What value here should be used? (this 6 is some decimal places, but how to set full 1400 USDT?)

What about gasPrice?
